# CAShapeLayer path animation shrinking before completing animation

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransform, cabasicanimation

I am trying to animate a rotation of a layer's CGpath.

The rotation works perfectly, but for some reason, the path seems to shrink, then get bigger again. I just want it to show a rotating animation. I don't want it to shrink

here is a video.

[image]

here is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var overlayView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)
    let mask = UIBezierPath.drawSquare(width: 100, center: view.center)
    
    // Makes it so we can see through the center of the view
    maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
    path.append(mask)
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    overlayView.layer.mask = maskLayer
}

@IBAction func rotateView(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath.drawSquare(width: 100, center: overlayView.center)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: overlayView.frame)
    
    let bounds: CGRect = maskPath.cgPath.boundingBox
    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    
    let radians = 90 / 180.0 * .pi
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: center.x, y: center.y)
    transform = transform.rotated(by: radians)
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -center.x, y: -center.y)
    maskPath.apply(transform)

    path.append(maskPath)
    
    // create new animation
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim.toValue = path.cgPath
    
    (overlayView.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer)?.add(anim, forKey: "path")

}

}

extension UIBezierPath{

static func drawSquare(width: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> UIBezierPath {
    let rect = CGRect(x: center.x - width/2, y: center.y - width/2, width: width, height: width)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: rect.origin)
    
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.close()
    return path
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "cutout box" is shrinking and growing because you're using **path** animation.

When you animate a path from one set of points to another, each point will take a straight line from its starting point to its ending point.

Couple ways to visualize this...

First, we'll add an "outline" frame to the cutout mask box:

[image]

as you see, each corner is taking a direct route to its next position.

If we highlight one side, it's maybe a bit more obvious:

[image]

and, we can number the corners for even more clarity:

[image]

So, if we want to rotate the square without changing its size, we *could* use keyframe animation and run the corners along a circle:

[image] [image]

or, much easier, rotate the mask **layer** instead of its path:

```
let radians = 90 / 180.0 * .pi
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
anim.toValue = radians
anim.duration = 1.0
(overlayView.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer)?.add(anim, forKey: "layerRotate")
```

[image]

No doubt we notice that the mask layer frame does not completely cover the overlayView frame.

So, we can fix that by making the mask layer frame larger.

We could calculate *exactly* how big it needs to be, but because shape layers are very efficient, we'll just make it a square, 1.5 times bigger than the longer axis:

[image]

so when it rotates, it covers the view:

[image]

and we finish with this:

[image]